# Django unittest result depends on test name

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I predefined few dicts in my test.
eg.

```
TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER = dict(
    time_discount=dict(
        discount_days=5,
        discount_percent=15
        )
    )
```

This dict goes to my model (JSONfield), then in my test, I am taking data from it. When I name test `test_add_the_rest_of_name` django detect predefined dicts, but when I name test eg. `test_time_sth` django gives me output

```
    discount = TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER.get("time_discount").get("discount_percent")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have noticed, that in the second case (`test_time_sth`) my predefined dict is empty according to django, no matter if I am taking data directly from dict or from model instance. If I name test differently, test pass. Does anyone have any clue why is it happening?

Minimal example:

Model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Offer(models.Model):
    details = JSONField()
```

Test:

```
TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER = dict(
    time_discount=dict(
        discount_days=10,
        discount_percent=25
        )
    )
class OfferTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.offer = Offer.objects.create(details=TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER)

    def test_special_offer_removed(self):
        self.offer.details.pop('time_discount', None)

    def test_timeframe_offer(self):
        discount = TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER.get("time_discount").get("discount_percent")

    def test_add_offer(self):
        discount = TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER.get("time_discount").get("discount_percent")
```

Traceback:

```
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_timeframe_offer (offers.tests.test_offer.OfferTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin1/Dokumenty/project/offers/tests/test_offer.py", line 142, in test_timeframe_offer
    discount = TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER.get("time_discount").get("discount_percent")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.006s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: minimal reproducible example added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not clean up properly after your tests. Everything that has been change in a test should be cleaned up at its end.

In your special case you are removing the key `time_discount` in your test `test_special_offer_removed`. Now depending on the order of the tests you might start your failing test after `test_special_offer_removed` and it will find the dictionary with the now missing key.

To prevent such problem make sure you are restoring the environment after every test: bring `TIME_DISCOUNT_OFFER` back to its original state at the end of `test_special_offer_removed`!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still don't know, why the test `test_add_offer` passed, but `test_timeframe_offer` failed (no matter what the order in the test is) despite the fact that they are the same. Also, I tried not to remove dict itself, but change `cls.offer` instance field. Should I define the dict from the beginning in tearDown? I made some workaround in my test so it passed, but  have no idea why the name in test is so crucial

Comment: Because it is run before `test_special_offer_removed` modified the dictionary. Tests are usually run in alphabetical order.